# Статическая линковка Qt 5.7 с Visual Studio 2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015

При запуске проекта изнутри студии проблем нет, но сам exe запускается только при условии, что в path прописано, где искать библиотеки, либо если сами эти библиотеки лежат в папке в проектом. Как-то это неудобно, по-моему. Особенно, когда речь идет о других компьютерах. То есть нужно взять исходники Qt и собрать их самостоятельно определенным образом. Да, я знаю, что в поисковике находится очень много статей на эту тему, но большинство хочет другой компилятор, или другую версию Qt или еще что-то. Найденный вариант, вроде бы подходящий по всем параметрам делал nmake несколько часов, после чего отказался его устанавливать. Поэтому очень бы хотелось получить конкретные инструкции для данного случая, потому что перспектива пробовать каждую, убивая на это по паре часов, не очень радует.

После вот  [этих](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-under-windows-or-linux-32-or-64-bit-static-or-dynamic-on-v) и вот  [этих](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484175/build-static-qt-project-with-visual-studio-2015) действий все еще проблемы. Во-первых, он не находит файл qwindowsd.lib (поиск его вручную тоже не нашел).

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'qwindowsd.lib'
```

При удалении этой строчки из списка библиотек появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol gethostname referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl QSysInfo::machineHostName(void)" (?machineHostName@QSysInfo@@SA?AVQString@@XZ)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WSAStartup referenced in function "public: __cdecl QWindowsSockInit::QWindowsSockInit(void)" (??0QWindowsSockInit@@QEAA@XZ)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WSACleanup referenced in function "public: __cdecl QWindowsSockInit::~QWindowsSockInit(void)" (??1QWindowsSockInit@@QEAA@XZ)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WSAAsyncSelect referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QEventDispatcherWin32Private::doWsaAsyncSelect(int,long)" (?doWsaAsyncSelect@QEventDispatcherWin32Private@@QEAAXHJ@Z)
```

Comment: Видимо, проблема в qwindowsd.lib. Потому что его везде говорят добавлять, но у меня линкер его не находит.

Comment: Ладно, файл открылся после добавления $(QTDIR)\plugins\platforms. Но опять вылезли четыре вышеперечисленные unresolved external symbol. Кто-нибудь может сказать, что это такое и что с этим делать?

Comment: Если при этом добавить ws2_32.dll из Windows SDK, то внутри студии запускается. Сам же exe выдает ошибку. `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".` Что это вообще должно означать?

Comment: Кстати, та же ошибка (про плагин) вылезает, если собирать все динамически, а потом пытаться запустить на другом компе (с копированием всех .dll от Qt и студии). Вариант с созданием там же plugins/platforms/qwindows.lib (dll) не помогает. (Сама с собой говорю)

Comment: Вообще пустые кавычки меня смущают. В подобных случаях у всех остальных с такой же проблемой этих кавычек нет. Зато есть строчка "available plugins are:", которой у меня нет.
Значит ли это, что где-то еще прописан путь к папке с плагинами? И если я явно указываю этот путь, то он перезаписывается? И в любом случае плагины не находятся? Если создать переменную QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH и задать путь к папке, где лежит plugins или platforms или qwindows, то пустые кавычки покажут этот путь.

Comment: Ох. Используйте комментарии для обсуждения и общения по теме. Вам стоит дополнить вопрос информацией, которую разместили в комментариях, тогда Вам с большей вероятностью помогут.